# Forward characterization of measurable functions?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, continuity, definition, measurable-functions

In topology, the standard definition of continuity works in the "backward" direction, since it puts a condition on the pre-images of a function rather than images:

> $f$ is continuous if the pre-image under $f$ of every open set is open.

However, there is an alternative definition of continuity that works in the "forward" direction:

> $f$ is continuous if $p\in\overline A\implies f(p)\in\overline{f(A)}$.

The standard definition of measurable functions is analogous to the first definition of continuity (just replace "open" with "measurable"). **Can measurable functions be defined without reference to pre-images, by analogy with continuity?**

---

**EDIT:** The original version of this question did not specify that I was looking for a definition without *any* use of pre-images. The [proposed duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285848/what-properties-are-preserved-under-a-measurable-mapping) has an answer that considers the "forward" direction, but it still uses pre-images in part of its formulation. First I made a [new post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4202555/can-measurable-functions-be-defined-with-pre-images) with a refined question, but was then kindly instructed to re-open this one.

Comment: This is a very reasonable question, but I doubt there is a satisfying answer. When the adjective is "open", there is a related operator "closure" (the connection to "open" is that the closure is the complement of the *interior* of the complement). When the adjective is "measurable", we would need something like the complement of the *??* of the complement, where *??* would be (I guess) the largest measurable subset of $A$, which is not well-defined.

Comment: @GregMartin The closure of $A$ is also the intersection of all closed sets containing $A.$ We could define the same operator for measurable sets, though the result will not be measurable in general. But it still might enable a definition of measurable functions.

Comment: There is a way to formulate "measurable space" as a particular type of uniform space.  The measurable functions correspond to the uniformly continuous functions.  And (I think?) a function $f$ is uniformly continuous iff it maps Cauchy nets to Cauchy nets.

Comment: @GEdgar Sounds interesting/promising. The epilogue of the answer in the proposed duplicate seemed to suggest a similar idea, but I don't know enough about filters/Stone spaces/Boolean algebras to understand it. It would be elegant if the measurable maps are precisely the continuous maps with respect to some topology.

Comment: @WillG: Images of measurable functions do not behave well. Part of the analysis of such things falls within the realm of Analytic sets. There is a whole branch in set theory that deals with these matters "[Descriptive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory)".

Comment: @OliverDiaz You could say the same thing of images of continuous functions in topology (open- and closed-ness is not preserved). However, there is still a good "forward" definition of continuity (see post)—it just doesn't rely on defining open/closed sets. Hence I wonder if the same could be true for measurability.

Comment: @WillG: But for continuity the characterization $f(\overline{B})\subset \overline{f(B)}$ is all you need. In measurability things become more involve.

Comment: One possible route is via Lusin's theorem: a function is measurable if and only if, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, it is continuous except on a set of measure $\varepsilon$.

Comment: I happened to ask the same at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453522/forward-definition-of-measurability , see there for an answer.

Comment: The characterization at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285848/what-properties-are-preserved-under-a-measurable-mapping does not use preimages if you use nets instead of filters.