# Is it possible to redefine measurable spaces such that measurable functions are not defined in terms of pre-image?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

We know that a measurable space is defined as a tuple $(X,\mathcal A)$, where $X$ is a set and $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra defined on $X$. A $\sigma$-algebra is traditionally defined as a collection of subsets such that the whole set is in collection and it is closed under complements and countable union. A function $f:(X,\mathcal A)\to (Y,\mathcal B)$ is called measurable if for every $U\in \mathcal B,\ f^{-1}(U)\in\mathcal A$. We note that this definition uses the pre-image as a central notion.

An analogous construction is a topology $\tau$ on a set $X$, where $\tau$ is defined as a collection of subsets of $X$ such that it contains the whole set and the empty set and is closed under arbitrary union and finite intersection. A function $f:(X,\tau)\to (Y,\tau')$ is called continuous if for every $U\in \tau',\ f^{-1}(U)\in\tau$. We again note that this definition uses the pre-image as a central notion.

But in the case of topology, there exists an equivalent characterization using the so called [Kuratowski closure operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_closure_axioms) $\bf c$ in terms of which continuous functions are defined as a function $f:(X,\mathbf{c})\to(Y,\mathbf{c}')$ such that $f(\mathbf c(U)) \subseteq \mathbf c'(f(U))$ for all $U\subseteq X$. We note that this definition does not use pre-images and is equivalent to the traditional definition of continuous functions.

Is there a similar reformulation of $\sigma$-algebras such that measurable functions also does not use pre-images in it's definition? In fact, is there a reformulation such that measurable functions can be defined as exactly those functions such that $f(g(U))\subseteq g'(f(U))$ for all $U\subseteq X$, where $g,g'$ are functions from power set of $X,Y$ to power set of $X,Y$ respectively?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285848/what-properties-are-preserved-under-a-measurable-mapping (In particular, if you use nets instead of filters in the characterization in my answer, you get a formulation that avoids mentioning inverse images.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What properties are preserved under a measurable mapping?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285848/what-properties-are-preserved-under-a-measurable-mapping)

Comment: @EricWofsey and Ramiro (sorry couldn't tag you properly ;-; ) I checked the discussion you posted. the idea of filters and nets does look good, but in the push forward of the filter, it still uses the pre-image in the back. I was kinda looking for an approach which uses the image as the criteria.

Comment: Maybe this MO post will interest you : [https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453522/](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453522/).